# Extracting features to feature classes from a REST service

Tags: shapefile, convert, feature-class, desktop-gis

I've seen this done before but I can't figure that out how to do it. How do you extract features from a REST service to a feature class (or shapefile)? I believe it involves adding a REST service link to a map in ArcGIS Online (AGOL) then opening in ArcGIS Desktop. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: [ArcREST](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST) can be used to extract features from a REST endpoint plus a host of other functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is registered with [OpenData](http://opendata.arcgis.com/), the service's OpenData page will allow you to [download the data](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/open-data/consumer/access-data.htm) in a variety of different formats including Shapefiles.

Another way to do this would be to [query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Query_Map_Service_Layer/02r3000000p1000000/) all the features and save the resulting JSON (see [sample JavaScript code](https://github.com/WSDOT-GIS/download-arcgis-features)), then use the [JSON to Features geoprocessing tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm) tool to create a feature class.